# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API - How to add more info to ProblemDetails when returning 4XX

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When returning for instance a NotFound() or similar I would like to be able to add information to the ProblemDetails.

Normally it returns:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "traceId": "|6c1f4b5217ce4746b7d7716f1ca9c785.c9406fc2_"
}
```

According to the Swagger doku it could look like:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "status": 0,
  "detail": "string",
  "instance": "string",
  "additionalProp1": {},
  "additionalProp2": {},
  "additionalProp3": {}
}
```

My question is - how do i add custom info to e.g. detail or additionalProp1?

Comment: You can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_NotFound_System_Object_) and pass in your model class as the parameter which you want to return

Comment: Kunai: I can create the ProblemDetails object myself and return it as NotFound(myOwnCreatedProblemDetailsObject). But I was wondering - if it was possible to e.g. add only the Details property - and the rest would be filled out with the information shown in the first code block - which is returned if I just use NotFound().